# Vector subspaces: basis and linearly independent elements

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have two questions that I am struggling with..

> 1. In a space of real functions we have a subspace defined by the set $V = \langle 1,x, \cos x, \sin x \rangle$ and its subspace defined by the set $W = \{f \in V\mid f(\pi) = 0\}$
>
> Find some basis of $W$.
>
> 2. How many linearly independent sequences of two elements are there in the space $\mathbb{Z^2_3}$?

I believe I can get the answer of the second problem even though I am doubting the method to be the most efficient one.
I think I got to a number $24$ to be the result but it was more about actually figuring it out by considering all the options for the first element of the sequence (cannot be the zero vector) and then all the options for the second element (cannot be a multiple of the first one)..
But I am pretty sure there must be some solution that uses more of linear algebra.

As to the first problem I am pretty lost as I don't really know what the problem means and how should I approach it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Like most questions in linear algebra, it boils down to solving a linear system of equations. First, note that the functions $1,x,\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are linearly independent and so form a basis for $V$. Thus, a general function in $V$ is of the form

$$ f(x) = a + bx + c \cdot \mathrm{cos}(x) + d \cdot \mathrm{sin}(x) $$

where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. We have $f \in W$ if and only if $f(\pi) = 0$ if and only if

$$ f \left( \pi \right) = a + b \pi -c = 0.$$

This is a linear equation for the coefficients $(a,b,c,d)$ of $f$ whose solution subspace is a three dimensional subspace $W'$ of $V' = \mathbb{R}^4$ given by

$$ W' = \mathrm{span} \{ (0,0,0,1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, \pi, 0 \}. $$

Translating this solutions back to $W$, we see that a basis of $W$ is given by

$$ W = \mathrm{span} \{ \mathrm{sin}(x), 1 + \mathrm{cos}(x), x + \pi \cos(x) \}. $$

Verify that you understand why the functions are linearly independent (just like the vectors spanning $W'$ were) and form a basis for $W$.

---

Regarding your second question, your method sounds good. The vector space $\mathbb{Z}_3^2$ has $3^2 = 9$ elements. Assuming we care about order, a sequence of two linearly independent elements $(v_1,v_2)$ consists of a non-zero vector $v_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3^2$ and a second vector $v_2$ that is not a multiple by a scalar of $v_1$.

For $v_1$, we have $8$ options. Given $v_1$, there are three vectors that are linearly dependent on $v_1$ - those are $0 \cdot v_1 = 0$, $1 \cdot v_1 = v_1$ and $2 \cdot v_1$. Make sure you understand why $0, v_1$ and $2 v_1$ are necessarily distinct. Thus, we are left with $9 - 3 = 6$ options for $v_2$. Finally, we get $8 \cdot 6 = 48$ as the answer. If we don't care about order, we indeed get $24$ options.

Comment: Very neat and well-explained. +1

Comment: You're implicitly using that $\{1,x,\sin x,\cos x\}$ is a linearly independent set (easy, but not obvious).

Comment: You are of course correct. I did not want to discuss why it is true, but I'll edit my answer to reflect the fact that I use it.

Comment: Thanks. So basicly I should just verify that the vectors  $\ (0,0,0,1)^T, (1, 0, 1, 0)^T, (0, 1, \pi, 0)^T$ are linearly independent which I can do easily by making a taking the matrix with those vecotors as rows and doing the Gauss elimination. From that we can clearly see the vectors are linearly independent. We also know that every linearly independent sequence in $V$ forms its basis so after translationg that back to $W$ we can say $({sin}(x), 1 + \mathrm{cos}(x), x + \pi \cos(x) )$ is its basis, correct?

Comment: The fact that the vectors $(0,0,0,1), (1,0,1,0), (0,1,\pi,0)$ are linearly independent can be seen just by looking at the vectors or by writing $a(0,0,0,1) + b(1,0,1,0) + c(0,1,\pi,0) = 0$ and then comparing components. The point is that once you know that they are linearly independent, then the corresponding functions will also be linearly independent.

Comment: More formally, the map $(a,b,c,d) \mapsto a + bx + c \sin(x) + d \cos(x)$ defines an isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $V$. If you know that some vectors are linearly independent, then their image under the map (the corresponding functions) will also be linearly independent. The isomorphism sends $W'$ to $W$ and allows you to translate questions about functions to questions about vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I understand that, but what is the actual basis of $W$ then?

Comment: and what if we wanted 2) but with sequences with 3 elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2^3$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32379/discussion-between-levap-and-tawi).